# Is it a right format to write on the website: A message from the creators of the (website name)

Tags: phrase-request

Can you please tell me is it a right format to name a section or video on the website: "A message from the creators of the (website name)." For example: A message from the creators of the Google. And there will be information where creators will briefly explain that Google its a search system to find any information in the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "the", unless "the" is part of the name of the website.  The name of "Google" is not "The Google".

> A message from the creator of HelloGiggles.com

But this doesn't tell me that it is information about how to use the site. And I don't really need to be told what the site is.

Not many websites have a "message from the creators" page.  On Stackexchange there is a [tour] and [help] center for each site.  You might want to consider why you need this page.

Comment: Thank you! Need this page because planning to have main video in the top of website where authors will briefly explain about their website, what it is and whats all about. Picture of the video will be with their photo and sentence on it: “A message from the creators of Google”. Or maybe “Appeal of the creators of Google”? Thank you again

Comment: Most of the times I've seen a website with a link or banner called "A message from...,"  it has been a request for donations.

Comment: So you feel it will be ok for me to use "A message from the creators of Google" in my case? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not a website designer.  It is correct grammar.  It seems odd. I would use a title like "Tour".